# Refresh DataGrid contents after Form is updated in flex (without reloading page)

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, refresh

I have an application that takes data from an external xml file in the form of datagrid .
When clicked on Datagrid, a form is displayed highlighting the row of datagrid i have selected.

Now the requirement is 
 1. Form should be editable (I have done that)
 2. When User changes data in the Form, the respective changes should be reflected to Datagrid contents (w/o the page being reloaded)  I have done dis by using an Update button, but it is implemented with the help of a page Reload which I dont want to use.
 So basically i want to Refresh  DataGrid contents after Form is updated .

I am using Adobe® Flash® Builder™ 4.6

Kindly Help !
Thanks for Reading :)

Comment: You should read up on the concept of [data binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7fff.html).

Comment: I got the answer 
event handling helped me :) 

Below is the code : 

public function initApp():void
{
viewempdata.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, updatedetails); 
}
   
public function updatedetails(event:Event):void
{   
dg.selectedItem.name = empname.text;             dg.selectedItem.emailid=empemailid.text;
dg.selectedItem.age=empage.text;
dg.selectedItem.dept=empdept.text;
}

where :
viewempdata (id of my FORM )

empname,empemailid,empage,empdept (ids of textvalues in the FORM)

dg (id of datagrid)